# php session safety

Tags: php, session

I looked this up a while ago and it was and still is quite vague to me. I'd like to know if the following things about sessions are correct when I use this: `$_SESSION['username'] = "pete";`

- `$_SESSION` is a global variable that can only be changed on the server
- When `$_SESSION['username']` is declared a cookie will be set on the client-side
- This means the client can view the data but not edit it
- When `$_SESSION['username']` is declared a cookie will be set on the server-side as well

If the third statement is true then why cant I find the cookie with the username inside it if I log in? I do find a session cookie but it contains a code like `tkcsq66lucpra9m7j3ogqol5h7`. Not quite a name now is it?

Comment: Cookie will just contain Session ID. And your session data is stored on file or db based on your php.ini setting for "session.save-path".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> `$_SESSION` is a global variable that can only be changed on the server

It's a super-global … but one that is populated with saved data between executions of scripts.

> When `$_SESSION['username']` is declared a cookie will be set on the client-side

No. A cookie (unless the settings have been fiddled with) will be created when the session is started

> This means the client can view the data but not edit it

No. The cookie contains the session id, not the data

> When `$_SESSION['username']` is declared a cookie will be set on the server-side as well

Cookies are stored only on the client. Data will be stored on the server, and will be associated with an identifier that is stored in the cookie sent to the browser.

> If the third statement is true then why cant I find the cookie with the username inside it if I log in?

It isn't true.

> I do find a session cookie but it contains a code like tkcsq66lucpra9m7j3ogqol5h7.

That's the identifier.

If you were building a session system yourself (instead of using PHP's built in library for it) then you might store something like this in a database:

```
session                     key       value
tkcsq66lucpra9m7j3ogqol5h7  username  pete
```

The session library can then populate `$_SESSION` with `"username" => "pete"` when a session is started and it receives a cookie with `sessionId=tkcsq66lucpra9m7j3ogqol5h7` in it.

PHP's built in system isn't so cheap and nasty (and does it transparently so you don't need to worry about the implementation details).

Comment: Your explanation is ten times more clear than the garbage I found on the net. Thanks dude.

Comment: What happens when the user would edit the session id in the cookie?

Comment: Then they have a *tiny* chance of hijacking someone else's session, but will almost certainly try to access a non-existent one. I've no idea if PHP will create a new session with that id or throw an exception. It's trivial enough to test if you're interested.

Comment: Thats all I need to know about sessions for now. Keep doing what you're doing by the way, I've seen some helpful answers of yours on other questions.

Answer (score 0):

this string "tkcsq66lucpra9m7j3ogqol5h7" in the cookie is the session identifier.
all `$_SESSION` data is accessible to server only.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie on the client side is a reference to the contents of the session on the server side  in whatever storage mechanism that is being used to store the session.

So if your session settings store session data in files, there will be a file somewhere on your server named tkcsq66lucpra9m7j3ogqol5h7 that has the session data (or if you, say, use memcached for session data there'll be a memcached key with that session key).